# I find a "mistake" on p.40 in Ahlfors' "Complex Analysis"?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers, power-series

On the third edition of Ahlfors' Complex Analysis, page 40 Theorem 2 it states: we conclude that
\begin{equation*}
\left|\frac{R_n(z)-R_n(z_0)}{z-z_0}\right| \leq \sum_{k=n}^{\infty} k|a_k|\rho^{k-1}
\end{equation*}
The expression on the right is the remainder term in a convergent series.

I have trouble in understanding that $\sum_{k=n}^{\infty} k|a_k|\rho^{k-1}$ is convergent.

We know that $1/{\rho}>1/R=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sup \sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$. So, there exists an $N$ such that $1/\rho>\sqrt[k]{|a_k|},  |a_k|<\frac{1}{\rho ^k}$ for all $k\geq N$. If $n\geq N$, we have
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{k=n}^{\infty} k|a_k|\rho^{k-1}\leq\sum_{k=n}^{\infty} k\frac{1}{\rho^k}\rho^{k-1}=\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}\frac{k}{\rho}
\end{equation*}
Since $\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}\frac{k}{\rho}$ is not convergent, we cannot conclude that  $\sum_{k=n}^{\infty} k|a_k|\rho^{k-1}$ is convergent. How to prove $\sum_{k=n}^{\infty} k|a_k|\rho^{k-1}$ is convergent?

Thanks for eulersgroupie's answer. I'd like to add more details. The radius of convergence of $\sum_{1}^{\infty}na_n z^{n-1}$ is $R$. Since $\rho <R$, $\sum_{1}^{\infty}na_n \rho^{n-1}$ is  absolutely convergent. So, $\sum_{1}^{\infty}n|a_n| \rho^{n-1}$ is convergent. Finally, $\sum_{k=n}^{\infty} k|a_k|\rho^{k-1}$ is convergent.

Martin R's answer likes a magic and I really appreciate it. It solves my question directly.

This a question from Ahlfors' Complex Analysis. I show you the whole context of the question below. I have trouble understanding the statement with red line.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$1/\rho>\sqrt[k]{|a_k|}$ for sufficently large $k$ is correct, but not good enough to prove the convergence.

Choose $r$ such that $\rho < r < R$, then $1/{\rho}>1/r > 1/R=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sup \sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$ so that $1/r>\sqrt[k]{|a_k|}$ for sufficiently large $k > N$. Then
$$
\sum_{k=n}^{\infty} k|a_k|\rho^{k-1}\leq \sum_{k=n}^{\infty} \frac{k}{\rho} \left( \frac{\rho}{r}\right)^k
$$
and that series is convergent.

Comment: It's an amazing answer! Cool!

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate eulergroupie's answer, Ahlfor's shows in the middle of p.39 that the radius of convergence of a power series $\sum_{n} a_nz^n$ is equal to the radius of convergence of the power series of series obtained by termwise differentiation of the series $\sum_{n} na_n z^{n-1}$. He proves this using the Hadamard formula established at the top of the page, and an elementary argument to show that $n^{1/n} \to 1$.

It thus follows that the series $\sum_{n} na_n z^{n-1}$ has radius of convergence $R$ (the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n} a_nz^n$) by assumption as far as I can see), and since $\rho<R$ therefore implies the series converges absolutely and uniformly for $z$ with $|z|\leq \rho$, and thus $\sum_{k=n}^\infty k|a_k|\rho^{k-1}$ is the tail of a convergent series.